# How do I add a Windows 7 Homegroup folder to iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, homegroup

I have a HTPC running Windows 7 with music in the public Music folder. Is it possible to add this folder to the iTunes library on another computer in the same homegroup?

The obvious *File->Add Folder to Library* menu option doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it. It's not the router, it's not the firewall, it's a simple matter of folder selection for sharing. Here's how I did it:

1. On PC running Windows 7 open the Start menu and click on Computer
2. Click on the Music folder until you get to the iTunes library folder
3. Select "Share with" from the toolbar and select your homegroup
4. Done!

Answer (score 0):

How about the Properties of the existing library.  Then Add folder.  If this does not allow you to add the network share, then my guess is that the current user does not have permissions on the distant, network machine.

At the risk of repeating myself, you need to share out the folder and assign permissions before adding it to the library.

Comment: Homegroups in Windows 7 are supposed to handle all of that for you, and indeed I can browse to the folder and see the files in iTunes, I can copy them to my local library by dragging them from Explorer, but when I add the folder nothing happens.